# Javascript modal window call function - bootstrap UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have HTML code into variable `contentStr` and I try to call this HTML code in modal window with twitter bootstrap UI function `modal()` so I do this:

```
   $(contentStr).modal();
```

but this code render for me a hidden modal window and html looks like this:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop  in"></div>
<div class="in" aria-hidden="true">
    <h5>Hog Wild Pit BBQ</h5>
    <p>662 E 47th Street South, Wichita, KS, United States</p>
    <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-qyHUXQNgfHM/Ufl7s8AQY2I/AAAAAAAABxk/u3X0W75mhGo/w500-h500-s0/photo.jpg">
    <br>(316) 522-7636
    <br><a target="_blank" href="http://www.hogwildpitbbq.com/">http://www.hogwildpitbbq.com/</a>
    <br>The food was tasty with good-sized portions and was served quickly. My wife, two-year old daughter an I ate one dinner with the turkey, ribs, and pulled pork. Others might want to eat more but that was good for us. The turkey was a little dry but
    otherwise everything was great. The corn and cole slaw sides were decent. The Texas toast was good and sauces were great. Pickles and chilies were also available.
    <br>
    <br>Traveling through Texas, Oklahoma, and Kansas today I found a new BEST BAR-B-Q with Hog Wild Pit Bar-B-Q. Just as quick it was served to me I finished. Back on the road again... EAT HERE...you will make it back and you will remember.
    <br>
    <br>Favorite BBQ so far unless I have the time to throw it down on the grill!
    <br>
    <br>Best Barbeque in Kansas.
    <br>
    <br>I've eaten at the Hog Wild on 47th street a few times and it has always been excellent. Their ribs are the best I've ever had. I live in the Memphis, TN, area and have not found anywhere around here that has ribs nearly as good as Hog Wild.
    <br>
    <p>1092.941km</p>
    <p>9 hours 23 mins</p>
    <p>950.56km</p>
    <p>08:38:0</p>
    <button id="dodaj">Add to timeline</button>
</div>
```

SO I can't see, I can't show modal window just a opacity background is there.

How I can solve this?

Comment: So this code wont to show HTML in modal, just show HTML below my other content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a sample, so you can do this as you wich.

Please, [take a look](http://jsbin.com/upINuh/3/edit?html,output)

The first thing you need to do is conver the html string to truth html.

```
var myModal = '<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">  <div class="modal-header">    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>  </div>  <div class="modal-body">    <p>One fine body…</p>  </div>  <div class="modal-footer">    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>  </div></div>'
```

You have to set up the class property to `"modal fade"`. Notice that I using `'` to wrap my html string, and at my html string I use `"`, it's a important thing.

Then, I call the `$(myModal).modal('show');` passing the parameter `'show'`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: well becouse my situation is a little bit complicated, I cant do this, so this dont work, I first click on marker then I must call modal

Comment: I made a sample as you want, please take a look